# Origin of "Well, well, well. What do we have here?"

Tags: phrase-origin

Google will not tell me where this phrase originates. Does Stack Exchange have the answer?

Comment: You mean specifically those exact words? What about *What have we here?* Or even *What's this?*

Comment: Do non-idiomatic phrases even *have* origins? To me, it just looks like it should be interpreted literally.

Comment: Googling around, it seems like it might be an internet meme.

Comment: I would also say that 'well, well' is the original which expanded to 'well, well, well'. Also as @FumbleFingers suggests, 'What have we here' is probably the more common phrasing.

Comment: Daniel is right. I just cut & pasted the question into Google, and "Instant" suggested the next word I might like to type was **meme**. Someone else can find out if its origins are interesting - I can't be bothered.

Comment: This might be a variation on the: "’ello, ’ello, ’ello.  What’s going on here then?" that the quintessential British [bobby](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bobby)/[Plod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Plod) utters on encountering something suspicious.  _The Phrase Finder_ touches on that [here](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/how-do-you-do.html) but doesn't give any further detail.

Comment: The Invisible Man, 1933: Constable Jaffers, upon entering the Lion's Head Inn, gave a hearty "Well, well, " etcetera. My favorite line from the good Constable, however, was his response upon "seeing" the Invisible Man: **"'E's all eaten awye!"**

Comment: There was a film adaptation in 1933. Is the quote from the film or the novel (pub 1897)?

Comment: From _A New and Mery Enterlude Called the Triall of Treasure_ (https://books.google.com/books?id=Lm4JAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA23&dq=%22what+have+we+here%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiirsi3w5vMAhUBxGMKHdPvAdgQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22what%20have%20we%20here%22&f=false) (1567): "_Gredy-gutte._ Why **what have we here**, Jesus, benedicitie!/I holde twenty pounde it is Baalam's asse,/Nay tis a colte, I see his tayle by the masse!"

Answer (score 8):

The phrase has been used before, but the meme seems to have taken off in May 2009, according [Google Insights](http://www.google.com/insights/search/#q=what%20do%20we%20have%20here,well%20what%20do%20we%20have%20here,well%20well%20what%20do%20we%20have%20here,well%20well%20well%20what%20do%20we%20have%20here&cmpt=q). The blue line is "what do we have here", and the others are co-incident "[[well] well] well what do we have here":

[image: Google Insights chart]

The map on the page shows the interest in the phrase is predominantly from the USA.

I expect May 2009 seems to be when this motivational poster spoof spread around the internet:

[image: motivational poster]

[MotiFake](http://www.motifake.com/18200) ("The ORIGINAL Demotivational Poster Community")  says it was created 28th August 2008.

Comment: What do we have **[here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AbMy1.jpg)**?

Answer (score 6):

"Well, well, well. What do we have here then?" An old phrase used on occasion by police officers in Great Britain upon the discovery of people engaging in criminal acts. Dates back to the Victorian era.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @zpletan Every film/TV policeman from before 1970

Answer (score 0):

HAMLET, Act 3 Scene 1 - Shakespeare

I humbly thank you; well, well, well .

Comment: Well, well (, well)  isn't this interesting....

Answer (score -1):

It's from The Wizard of Oz (1039), when the Wicked Witch of the West corners Dorothy in her castle.

Comment: How do you know this was the origin? Put it differently: how would anybody be reading your answer know it is correct or not?

Comment: I think you mean 1939, not 1039. The film's not *that* old.