# What does "Well, no more" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

English has many complicated expressions. Can you explain to me the expression "Well, no more" in this paragraph? Thank you so much!

> What women want is supposed to be some sort of unsolved mystery that has haunted males, and even females, since the dawn of civilization. **Well, no more**

Comment: _That is no longer the case._

Comment: *Well,* I guess @Helmar is right.

Comment: Interestingly (well, to me at least), I can't find any previous ELU questions asking about the use of ***well*** as an "introductory" [discourse marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_marker). Which position usually implies *in contrast to what was said previously*, whereas if used in an *intermediate* position within an utterance it usually implies something like *the phrasing I'm about to use next may not be quite appropriate / accurate, but it's the best I can come up with quickly enough to keep this conversation going.*

Comment: I actually closevoted for lack of prior research (the "meaning* of the highlighted words should be obvious to anyone in ELU's target user base). But taking particular account of the usage distinction I pointed out above, I'm now inclined to think the best option might be to migrate this question to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree.  This seems to a be an eternal problem of this forum.  And it's exactly beginner english speakers who would find it the least obvious that this isn't the forum for them.  So no wonder this happens all the time

Comment: @Some_Guy: ***If*** OP had indicated that he understood perfectly well what the cited example *means*, and was simply asking for a more in-depth examination of the *syntax* and / or its relationship to superficially similar usages such as *intermediate* positioning, I'd have happily endorsed it being asked here. But as things stand, it's [*a bit, well... **basic***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+bit+well+basic%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Loosely related: [Origin of “Well, well, well.  What do we have here?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/51604/26083)

Comment: why have we voted to close rather than migrate?  This isn't an inherently bad question is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things happening here which could cause confusion. Firstly 'well' is being used as an [exclamation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/well).

The second problem is that [ellipsis](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ellipsis) is being used to omit a number of words. In this case something like 'It is a mystery' which would turn the phrase into the sentence 'Well, it is a mystery no more.'

The meaning is that, according to the writer, the mystery of what women want has been solved and, by implication, is about to be revealed by the writer in the rest of the piece of writing. The 'Well' is merely an exclamation to add emphasis and intrigue the reader.

Comment: It would probably help to say explicitly what the omitted words were.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You all are very good at English!

Comment: @AndrewLeach Quite right, I've edited my answer to include possible omitted words.