# Origin of "All right, what's all this, then?!"

Tags: phrases, british-english, phrase-origin, catch-phrases

Wonder where is the origin of this phrase? I first heard it on Monty Python. Typical scenario being, a sort of clueless Scotland yard cop enters the scene and asks "alright... what's all this then?"

Since it looked like it was being used satirically in Monty Python, I suspect the origin of it must be older.

Comment: Most policemen are depicted as saying "'Ello, 'ello, 'ello, what's goin' on 'ere, then?"

Comment: Yes indeed. But how did that come about?

Comment: To clarify my question, there is no similar stereotype of American or any other English speaking country cops. So, there must be someplace where this brit cop 'meme' originated from.

Comment: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Where-did-the-British-popular-culture-cliche-of-policemen-saying-ello-ello-ello-come-from) thinks it's *Dixon of Dock Green;* I reckon the stereotype is older than that.

Comment: Also an almost identical question already on ELU: [Well well well, what do we have here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51604/origin-of-well-well-well-what-do-we-have-here)

Comment: 16 To clarify your question, there might be no similar stereotype of cops in America or any other English-speaking country and if there was, 'sereotype' would hardly be appropriate. So, there must be someplace where this brit cop 'meme' originated from

Comment: Isn't it in the film version of Mary Poppins? The books date back to the 30s.

Comment: "What's all this" is an idiom for "what's going on here".  Nothing particular remarkable, and there's no reason to believe it has an identifiable (and unique) origin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The earliest match for the phrase that a Google Books search finds is more than a century old. From Eden Phillpotts, "[Quite Out of the Common](https://books.google.com/books?id=K182AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA269&dq=%22what+%27s+all+this+then%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj17eHXtdHaAhWprVQKHaunAx4Q6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22what%20%27s%20all%20this%20then%22&f=false)," in *Punch* (April 11, 1900):

> There followed no immediate response; then three boys assembled under my arch, and they formed a nucleus or focus about which a small crowd of the roughest possible persons, male and female, collected. Last of- all a policeman came also.
>
> "Now then!" he said, "**what's all this, then?**"
>
> The miserable boys took entire credit to themselves for discovering me perched aloft. They pointed me out and called attention to the Jubbulpore rope dangling from the lamp, and elaborated their own theories.
>
> Very properly the constable paid no attention to them, but addressed all his remarks to me.
>
> "You up there," he asked, "what d'you think you're plyin' at?"

So in 1900 we already have "what's all this, then?" presented as a typical query that a London policeman of modest education might pose to a small crowd that has gathered for no immediately discernible purpose.

I imagine that it originated as a variant of a predictably common constabulary question along the lines of "What's all this commotion [or *disturbance* or *excitement*] about?" but I haven't attempted to find historical antecedents of the specific wording that the poster asks about.

Comment: A good answer to what is a perfectly normal question that is not limited to policemen. *“What’s all this, then?” = “What is the nature of all that I am referring to.”* The "then" is interesting, OED describes it as **"5. (As a particle of inference, often unemphatic or enclitic.) That being the case; ... on that account; therefore, consequently, as may be inferred; so. now then:** See *"A review of the affairs of France*" (1705) *Now tho' this were true, tho' I see no pretended proof of it, yet I may be allow'd to ask **"What is all this** to what they are out of purse for Catalonia?"